# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' in on_message event

Tags: python, discord.py

I want that when I write something in the channel `927235996158922802` the bot will repeat it in (channelO),
 but I got the error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channelO = bot.get_channel(926945495413301290)
    if message.channel.id == 927235996158922802:
        await bot.get_channel(channelO).send(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nonetype` error occurs when your bot doesn't have the channel in its internal cache. That's why you should use `await bot.fetch_channel` instead which is an API call. `message` stores other data (e.g. server, author, channel, etc.) you have to get `message.content`.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: # To make sure your bot will ignore messages sent by itself
        return

    if message.channel.id == 927235996158922802:
        channelO = await bot.fetch_channel(926945495413301290)
        await channelO.send(message.content)
```

***You have to enable [`intents.messages`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents%20message#discord.Intents.messages)!***

Comment: @Mohamed Badran Did it work?

Comment: you didn't understand me, I mean that when I write something in channel1 the bot repeat it in channel2 not in the same channel

Comment: You're right. I thought it was the same ID, but it wasn't now it should work. I used [`fetch_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch%20channel#discord.Client.fetch_channel) instead of `get_channel` which is an API call that doesn't rely on the bot's internal cache.

Comment: Thanks it worked